# Two Different Hard Drives at 100% usage in my custom desktop

Tags: hard-drive, windows-10

I recently had an issue where my computer was unusable, and hard drive was always at 100%, so I tested the hard drive, and sure enough, it said something along the lines of "too many failures", which I assumed to mean my hard drive was crashing, and being 7 years old, I assumed it was true.

So I just bought a new WD Black 1TB drive. I had some trouble installing Windows, which seemed like it may have been another HD issue, but on the 3rd try, it finally installed (I had to disconnect my 2nd drive). I got it up and working, and it's been fine for around 3 weeks of low usage, but now it's showing the same symptoms as the first drive. 100% usage in task manager, but my individual processes are sometimes showing 0.1 MB/s or less with 100% disk usage. I can't get perfomance monitor to come up, as windows is pretty much unusable and it takes 5+ minutes to get the start menu and other things to work.

It seems unlikely that the same systems across hard drives would show up. Can someone guess as to whether this is an issue with the SATA cable, or is this an issue on the motherboard? My 2nd drive with pictures and other files does not seem to have a problem.

Comment: temporary stop superfetch service. Is the 100% disk usage gone?

Comment: If you think it's the SATA cable, try another cable.  And while your second drive may not be showing obviously problems, if may be what's causing your disk problems (by polluting the bus).  if you leave the 2nd drive unhooked, does the computer behave as expected?

Comment: I was able to get perfmon to come up at one point yesterday, and didn't notice anything with prefetch in the name, but I'll try it when I can. The secondary drive is older, so maybe it is causing an issue. I'll try to unplug it and see what happens. Hopefully I can get the contents, because it has some important things we want to keep.

Comment: Seems to be working better after trying both suggestions. I'll probably turn superfetch back on to improve the performance, and then monitor to see how it does. @Ƭᴇcʜιᴇ007 if you'll add an answer, I'll mark yours as correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While your second drive may not be showing obviously problems, it may still be what's causing your disk problems, by polluting the bus.

Try leaving the 2nd drive unhooked, and see if things behave. :)